# Where can I get texinfo documentation for CMake, for example?

Tags: info

Since texinfo is kind of *the* help format for emacs, I hope the question is not too much off topic...

I'm starting to learn cmake and not having a texinfo documentation hurts a bit. Is there a way to convert the qt-help that's offered on the cmake page or any other solution?

Many thanks,
Markus

Comment: Although, this is not an answer to the direct question. The Emacs mode provided with CMake contains commands like `cmake-help-command`, `cmake-help-variable` etc. that can be used to retrieve information.

Comment: Thanks, that does help.I fear that texinfo as a perfect help for emacs is dying :(

Comment: @Markus, I feel your pain and look with sadness on people's disinterest in info. Fortunately,  Texinfo is the official documentation format of the GNU project, so it will always be around. For systems that use Sphinx, such as CMake, it's not too bad to generate the docs in info. I detailed the steps here. I would also recommend communicating interest in Texinfo/info to the project authors.  Even better, submit patches to generate texinfo.  Adding it is often a few lines in the make file.  They won't include it if they don't think people want it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65100142/5065796

Answer (score 1):

CMake help is built with Sphinx, which can generate Texinfo. You can build it yourself, and CMake 3.12.0 [is going to](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2146)  build it given `--sphinx-info` configure flag or `-DSPHINX_INFO` CMake flag. Example [cmake.info](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/uploads/e06381b1797b0f9ff3ad1fee582d7e78/cmake.info).